# How to exchange the space for backslash and a double quote using replace in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I'm coding a Java app to store paths in a particular format, so I need to escape some characters in order to put the paths in a database, but I cannot do it properly:
The original string looks like this:

`ML Database Prototype\\NAS-500\\`

and I need it in this particular format:

`"\"ML\ Database\ Prototype\\NAS-500\""`

So far I'm trying to do it using

```
String str = "ML Database Prototype\\NAS-500\\";

newStr = ( "\"\""+str+"\"" ).replace(" ","\" ");

System.out.println(newStr);
```

`""WT" Database" Prototype\\DR0151-populated"`

Comment: Is that replacement string _literal_ text, or is that something which would appear on the RHS assignment in your Java code?

Comment: Is it should be as it shows: `"\"ML\ Database\ Prototype\\NAS-500\""` I'm not sure replace() is the right way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use as follows and will work:

```
newStr = ( "\"\\\""+str+"\\\"\"" ).replace(" ","\\ ");
```

The output for this is:

```
"\"ML\ Database\ Prototype\\NAS-500\""
```